# QGIS custom forms using python logic

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, python-2.7, qgis-custom-widgets

I use QGIS and I want to work with custom forms using python logic and I try to follow this [manual](https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/).  In my custom qu I add one new pushButton and I want for example for educations rules to open some image.  But that dont work dont show me anything,any idea where I have wrong in my python code ?

Here the python code :

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import os
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget

nameField = None
myDialog = None
def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    control = dialog.findChild(QWidget, "MyLineEdit")
    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog
    global nameField
    nameField = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"Name")
    buttonBox = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox,"buttonBox")
    pushButton = dialog.findChild(QPushButton,"pushButton")

    # Disconnect the signal that QGIS has wired up for the dialog to the button box.
    pushButton.accepted.disconnect(myDialog.accept)

    # Wire up our own signals.
    pushButton.accepted.connect(validate)

def validate():
    filename='C:/Users/username/Desktop/image.jpg'
    os.startfile(filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `pushButton.clicked`  rather and `pushButton.accepted`.